# How to use an alias in an AVG function

Tags: sql, database, select, average

I have the following code below and I'm trying to get an AVG for the 3 columns.

```
 SELECT 
    (SUM(score) * .3) As score_a,
    (SUM(score) * .6) As score_b,
    (SUM(score) * .8) As score_c

     --now I want to get the AVG of the above scores
    AVG(score_a + score_b + score_c) As avg_score
 FROM score_table
```

but this does not work. The error I'm getting is "Invalid column name score_a".
I'm using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Sorry, I actually corrected my code above. I still get the same error.

Comment: You can't, because the alias won't exist until the completion of the `SELECT` statement.  What is the larger context you're trying to do this in, and what's your RDBMS (different solutions available).  Assuming `score` is an int, are you accepting a result as a double/float value (ie - would it be permissable to mathematically refactor the way the average statement is written)?

Comment: how you will get AVG of a single number ? you are actually adding all the scores and applying AVG on that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AVG()` is an aggregate function that takes values from multiple ***rows*** and gives their average.

You're trying to average 3 ***columns***.

I your specific case, it can be done using algebra.

```
SELECT 
  (SUM(score) * .3)                       As score_a,
  (SUM(score) * .6)                       As score_b,
  (SUM(score) * .8)                       As score_c,
  (SUM(score) * ((0.3 + 0.6 + .8) / 3.0)) As score_avg
FROM
  score_table
```

In a more generalised case, you're limited by the fact that you can't reference a column you just defined in another column...

```
SELECT
  a + 1      AS inc_a,
  inc_a * 2  AS this_is_invalid
FROM
  your_table
```

You'd either need to repeat yourself, or use a sub query...

***Repetition***

```
SELECT 
  (SUM(score) * .3)                                                 As score_a,
  (SUM(score) * .6)                                                 As score_b,
  (SUM(score) * .8)                                                 As score_c,
  ((SUM(score) * .3) + (SUM(score) * .3) + (SUM(score) * .3)) / 3.0 As score_avg
FROM
  score_table
```

***Sub Query***

```
SELECT
  score_a,
  score_b,
  score_c,
  (score_a + score_b + score_c) / 3.0 AS score_avg
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    (SUM(score) * .3)                                               As score_a,
    (SUM(score) * .6)                                               As score_b,
    (SUM(score) * .8)                                               As score_c
  FROM
    score_table
)
  AS data
```

Comment: Hmm, I think I'd recommend putting an extra set of parenthesis around `SUM(score) * (0.3 + 0.6 + .8)`, to make it more explicit.  Of course, this won't _necessarily_ give the same results, given float/double issues (And if the OP wants the score rounded to the nearest point...)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
 SELECT 
    (SUM(score) * .3) As score_a,
    (SUM(score) * .6) As score_b,
    (SUM(score) * .8) As score_c,
    AVG(score_a + score_b + score_c) As avg_score
 FROM score_table
```

and see if that works for you?

Comment: Yes, actually this is what I have originally (I just corrected it above) but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

There's the brute-force method of doing the average manually, but it won't scale as well as you add columns. :)

```
SELECT CAST((score_a + score_b + score_c) / 3 AS DECIMAL(20,2)) As avg_score,
       score_a,
       score_b,
       score_c
FROM (
    SELECT (SUM(score) * .3) As score_a,
           (SUM(score) * .6) As score_b,
           (SUM(score) * .8) As score_c
    FROM score_table
    GROUP BY userid, gameid --Whatever you're grouping by here!
)
```

Comment: This won't work.  `AVG()` averages over rows, not columns.  It won't error, but it won't give an average of the 3 scores.

Comment: This won't even run for me (on DB2) - it's complaining about the fact that the other columns aren't part of an aggregate/not part of a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: MySQL (which I assume they're using) is a lot more liberal with its requirement for the `GROUP BY` rows than DB2 (although, as primarily a DB2 user, I'm sort of ashamed of myself for forgetting it).